# Links issue when I deploy my Hugo site as a Github Pages project

Tags: hyperlink, github-pages, hugo

I created a Hugo site that working well locally. I deployed my Hugo site as a Github Pages project via a /docs folder on the master branch. 
So now, I have my Github Page project and my URL looks like that:

https://myname.github.io/myrepository/myHugoSite.

I have a problem with my link. All my links redirect to https://myname.github.io/ but not https://myname.github.io/myrepository/ because my links are `/next-page/`. These links are working locally because I don't have a repository.

My question is: Do I have to add `/myrepository/` to all my links or there is another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your site prefix to the `baseUrl` parameter in the `config` file. In your case the prefix is `myrepository/`

If you are using TOML format in your config file it would look like this:

```
baseUrl = "https://myname.github.io/myrepository/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Higo 0.62.1 (and more recent), you can have portable links.

See [`bep/portable-hugo-links`](https://github.com/bep/portable-hugo-links/) as an example.

> truly portable Markdown links and images. No shortcodes used.

[This page](https://github.com/bep/portable-hugo-links/blob/78fd673abdcdcc5f02cacdf25b49a2da95f3de23/docs/d1.md) includes the following links, which would be rendered correctly both on GitHub and Hugi generated pages:

```
* [Blog Link1](../blog/p1/index.md)
* [Blog Link2](../blog/p2.md)
* [Home Page](/README.md)
* [Local Anchor](#et-illis-ossaque-loqui-ille)
```